# the Encrypt library requires the Mcrypt extension in setup of nginx with php7.2

Tags: php, nginx, php-7.2

After installing nginx and php 7.2 server on ubuntu18, it is giving error "The Encrypt library requires the Mcrypt extension." It is a codeignitor framework.

Answer (score 0):

mcrypt has been moved from php to pecl since 7.2

You still can install it.

Install dependencies

```
gcc make autoconf libc-dev pkg-config
install the lib itself
```

libmcrypt-dev
I assume php7.2 and pecl are installed so you just install mcrypt-1.0.1 (or whatever version is in rep.) with pecl

```
pecl install mcrypt-1.0.1
```